# I need help shifting all my formula references in a Google Sheets table by one cell to the right

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a table in Google Sheets right now that deals with growth from the most recent period (As compared to 2 periods ago, 3 periods ago, 4 periods ago, etc.). What I need help with is how to change all the formulas when I insert the most recent periods data. The simple question is this: in a very simplistic way, if I have a large amount of data that references one column (say A) how do I get all these formulas to then reference column B.

Another way of asking to make it clear, how do I get every reference in every formula to simply reference the next column over.

Example:

I have this:

```
= A + B
= C + D
= E + F
```

how do I get all of these to turn into:

```
= B + C
= D + E
= F + G
```

I just want all the letters in the formula to shift to the next letter in the alphabet.

Comment: Sorry, this posted weird, it should read: How do I turn A+B+C+D+E+F  into B+C+D+E+F+G

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking. Since this question is about Google Sheets formulas please use the corresponding syntax to show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].